# Image not Displayed as Expected in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a form where users enter their details along with their image. I've written code that gets the image and stores it in a column named 'image' as bin file, the data type of the column is a blob. However, when I try to display the image in the view, The image is not getting displayed.

**Controller**

```
<?php

public function showProfile($username)
{
    $user_details = User::get()->where('name', $username);
    return view('profile-page', ['user_details' => $user_details]);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/user-post') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type='hidden' value='{{Session::token()}}' name="_token">
        @foreach($user_details as $user)
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( {{$user->image}} ).'"/>
            <p>
            <h2>
                <center>hello This is {{$user->name}} </center>
            </h2>
            <h2>
                <center>I am a {{$user->nationality}} </center>
            </h2>
            <h2>
                <center>This great person was born on {{$user->dobday}}-{{$user->dobmonth}}-{{$user->dobyear}} </center>
            </h2>
            <h2>
                <center>Contact me here {{$user->email}} </center>
            </h2>
        @endforeach
    </form>
</div>
```

All the details are shown as expected except the image, what's the problem here?

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{base64_encode($user->image)}}" />

Comment: Tried this too , not working still

Comment: What's the source code?

Comment: you can see the code of controller and view above

Comment: I mean the output from browser.

Comment: this i the image source code from the browser
 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,RGFkIGFuZCBtZS5qcGc=" />
when i click on this link it shows 
The image "data:image/jpeg;base64,RGFkIGFuZCBtZS5qcGc=" cannot be displayed because it contains error

Comment: i changed data:image/jpeg to data:image and clicked the image source link , this time it doesnt show any error but just gives the name of the image in text and not the image

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake here:

```
base64_encode( {{$user->image}}
```

try like this:

```
{{ base64_encode($user->image) }}
```

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.{{base64_encode($user->image)}}.'"/>
               this is the code now , still the same prob